# Git tracks files in project's "old" folder

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

For some reason git captures changes in old folder.

I have the following directory tree:

```
project1
│   file1
│   ...
│
└───.git
    │   ...
```

I've copied `project1` directory and named it as `project2`
When I open `project2` folder in vscode, it shows git files that are changed in `project1` folder.

Is git somehow uses absolute paths and I need do something for it to understand that it's now in different directory?

Comment: If you copied it whilst those files were being changed, then that makes sense. Try changing a file in `project1` and you should not see that change in `project2`

Comment: What prints `cd project2 && git config core.worktree` ? `echo $GIT_WORK_TREE` ?